# Enable different States inside of buttons SwiftUI

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, boolean, state

Problem:

Within a button I have states which do different things for example hide the tools and the navigation but for some reason I can't show the pencil panel after these views are hidden, any ideas?

```
@State var showPencilPanel:Bool = false
@Binding var showTools:Bool
@Binding var navOpen:Bool


                                    Button(action: {
                                        
                                        self.showTools = false
                                        self.navOpen = false
                                        self.showPencilPanel = true
                                        
                                    })

                
                            
                {
                                        VStack {
                                            Spacer()
            
                                            Image("Text Btn").resizable().renderingMode(.original)
                                                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                            Text("Text").font(.system(size: 10.0)).foregroundColor(.black)
                                            Spacer()
            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .position(x: 60, y: 640)
            
            }
                ZStack {

                    Color.white.opacity(0).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack (alignment: .center) {
                    
                        //Show Pencil
                    
                        if self.showPencilPanel {
                                MyCanvas(canvasView: canvasView, selectedImage: Binding(get: { selectedImage }, set: { selectedImage = $0 } ))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use `.zindex` for that

```
MyCanvas(canvasView: canvasView, selectedImage: Binding(get: { selectedImage }, set: { selectedImage = $0 } ))
.zindex(5)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/zindex(_:)